# prometheus rate on series by regex

Tags: prometheus

I am using the following query to get some metrics based on the name:

```
{__name__=~"bus_listener.+_processed"}
```

There are multiple metrics that match this name and multiple apps are publishing these metrics.

I am trying to calculate a rate on this, with:

```
rate({__name__=~"bus_listener.+_processed"}[5m])
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
vector cannot contain metrics with the same labelset
```

I cannot use recording metrics, I only have access to grafana, which reads metrics from prometheus.

How can I get this rate using a regex?

Answer (score 18):

Sounds like you have multiple metrics with the same labels (except for `__name__`). `rate()` keeps all labels except `__name__`, but it drops `__name__` to avoid any confusion. Meaning that if you have two time series like:

```
bus_listener_foo_processed{job="a_job"} 1
bus_listener_bar_processed{job="a_job"} 2
```

putting them through `rate()` will result in two time series both with the same labelset:

```
{job="a_job"} 0.1
{job="a_job"} 0.2
```

In theory you could duplicate the `__name__` label as some other label by using `label_replace()` first and applying `rate()` on the result of that, resulting in different labelsets for each original timeseries. However, since you can only compute `rate()` directly on a timeseries (not the output of another function) you can only do this by using [subqueries](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/), which is both heavyweight and slower than it would otherwise be:

```
rate(label_replace({__name__=~"bus_listener.+_processed"}, "old_name", "$1", "__name__", "(.+)")[5m:1m])
```

(Optionally replacing `1m` with something close to your scrape interval, so there's as little aliasing going on as possible.)

But ideally, if you do have access to the Prometheus configuration (which doesn't seem likely, since you say you can't use recording rules) you should use metric relabeling at ingestion time to extract the various bits of the metric name into separate labels, so you won't have to jump through hoops later on. Or have the service that exports the original metrics use labels instead of concatenating them into the metric name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have references for why the __name__ is removed, and why the same labelset is an issue?

Comment: The name is removed because it would most likely not be semantically correct after applying an operation. (E.g. what would the result of `up + 1` mean if it was still called `up`?) As to why the same label set is an issue, Prometheus expects only one instance of any one metric. Same label set means same metric, so two instances of the same metric. See https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/ , https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/380 and https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/5757 for details.

Answer (score 3):

I understand that you have multiple "bus_listeners" that report the _processed metrics.
Best way would be to have such metrics conform to Prometheus data model and have bus_listener as a label in metric instead of havint it embedded in metric name. That would require changing the application that emits these metrics.

If modifying application is not feasible then you can create conforming new metrics using recording rules.

If you create recording rule similar to:

```
 - record: processed_count
   expr: label_replace({__name__=~"bus_listener.+_processed", "bus_listener", "$1", "__name__", "bus_listener(.+)_processed")
```

then you can query new metric just fine:

```
  rate(processed_count[5m])
```

As you didn't provide exact metric names this rule may require some adjustments

Answer (score 0):

While this task can be solved by copying metric name from `__name__` label to other label with [label_replace()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_replace) function as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57807112/274937), this solution isn't ideal because it needs to use [subqueries](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/).

[MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) provides better solution for this task - `keep_metric_names` modifier. This modifier instructs the function to leave metric names. It can be applied to any PromQL and MetricsQL function, which removes metric names by default. For example, the following query should leave the original metric names after applying [rate()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rate) function:

```
rate({__name__=~"bus_listener.+_processed"}[5m]) keep_metric_names
```

This solution works faster than the solution with `label_replace()`, since it doesn't use `subqueries`.