# Prometheous Counters query

Tags: prometheus, promql

I've 5 counters defined for my application. I want to query all these counters in a single expression and want to know increase rate in last one hour.

1. my_app_a_start
2. my_app_b_start
3. my_app_c_start
4. my_app_d_start
5. my_app_e_start

How can I write such expression ? Rate is not a aggregated function

Answer (score 0):

This query will find all the range vectors you need in a single expression:

```
{__name__=~"my_app_.+_start"}
```

So, to get the rule I thought it was just to create a rule using:

```
increase({__name__=~"my_app_.+_start"}[1h])
```

But when I tried this I got the following error:

> vector cannot contain metrics with the same labelset

Then I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57788605/prometheus-rate-on-series-by-regex) on Stackoverflow which can help you to solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks.  Let me give some more details.  I'm  writing a Prometheus rule for these counters and want to know if any of these counter increased by 5 in last one hour.

Comment: Now I got you, I just changed my answer.